# Radio receiver output selector

Tags: radio, receiver, block-diagram

I have been given this project for my second year electronic. I have to make a circuit which has 3 audio signal inputs of different shapes like sine, square and triangle waves. The output has to be sequence of the three, like first will be the sine wave then the square and then the triangle.

I managed to get the circuit correct with the help of some senior students. It works for the purpose. However, I do not understand use of all the components used and building blocks in the circuits. I do know why some of the components are used in the circuits but not all. Could anyone help me understand that as I want to present the work with proper understanding.

And if someone could give pointers towards how to do system diagram for the given circuit.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: So this is a homework question? Are you writing a report how your circuit was designed, but unable to tell how why it is done like it is now, because the seniors told you how to do it without giving an explanation why it is done like this? Perhaps you should ask the seniors why they told you to do it like this then? Also, what parts you understand, and what parts not? Why this is a radio receiver, there is no radio anywhere?

Comment: I do understand basics of how circuit works and application of most of the components in there. If you could direct me on how can I start to put a block diagram, as I do not know how to do that.  And the part seniors did in this was the section with NAND gates. I was just told that they create a kind of logic selection to switch the levels of the S1 switch.

Comment: At the moment it's too broad a question. If you understand most of it, it's a waste of time explaining most of it. So be clearer about which bit(s) you don't understand.

Comment: This virtually identical to the question you asked two weeks ago. Not cool.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer yet because you need to show what you *do* understand first.

For the schematic do this:

1. Remove unnecessary wires by using the GND, Vcc and Vee symbols wherever you can. GND symbols should point down to "the ground".
2. Remove unnecessary kinks in wires.
3. Line up connections neatly such as to the right of S2, the mess to the right of U2A and again at S1 where there are many unnecessary cross-overs.
4. Put your three signal generators in a nice row or column, all aligned and with labels explaining their function (sine, triangle, square).
5. Use resistor symbols instead of cartoons. (We're all grown up now.)
6. Make it clear where the feedback path is on the op-amp. I can't find it.
7. When you've done all this you should be able to tighten up the schematic a bit.
8. Turn off the grid before taking the next screengrab.

Add your improved schematic to the post so we can compare for errors and to show your progress.